# Page jump to middle of section?

Tags: html

I'm trying to jump to a section of a web page but...

I want to jump to the center of it (rather than have the top of the page be the top of the section)

Is there any way to do this?

I was thinking if there was some kind of `#section + 50px` kind of thing?

Answer (score 1):

Because you wanted pure HTML, based on your tag, all I can come up with is this.

- Create an absolute element.
- Place it in the middle of the section.
- Point the anchor to said element.

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

section {
  position: relative; /* to make absolute child elements stay within it */
  min-height: 100vh;
}

section.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

section.brown {
  background-color: brown;
}

section.purple {
  background-color: purple;
}

.middle.element {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0px;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}

.dashed-line.middle.element {
  border-top: 1px dashed;
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li><a href="#yellow">Yellow</a></li>
 <li><a href="#brown">Brown</a></li>
 <li><a href="#purple">Purple</a></li>
</ul>

<section class="yellow">
  <div class="dashed-line middle element"><a id="yellow"></a></div>
</section>

<section class="brown">
  <div class="middle element"><a id="brown"></a></div>
</section>

<section class="purple">
  <div class="middle element"><a id="purple"></a></div>
</section>

<section></section>
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there another way to be more precise using other technology? I get the feeling you think that doing this with html is an unorthodox way

Comment: I think the solution is simple but clumsy. Using javascript (element.offsetHeight) would give a more accurate result, but it would require inline javascript code. Perhaps more characters for the same work.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this simple line of code in your previous page:-

```
<a href="next-page.html" onclick="window.scrollTo(0, 0)">Next Page</a>
```